# What is the equivalent of a circular reveal animation in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I was wondering how to implement a circular reveal animation from Android into Flutter. Also is there any resource for examples regarding Flutter animations?

Answer (score 3):

For Reveal Effect you have to use `CustomPainter` class.

```
class RevealProgressButtonPainter extends CustomPainter {
  double _fraction = 0.0;
  Size _screenSize;

  RevealProgressButtonPainter(this._fraction, this._screenSize);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var finalRadius =
        sqrt(pow(_screenSize.width / 2, 2) + pow(_screenSize.height / 2, 2));
    var radius = 24.0 + finalRadius * _fraction;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), radius, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RevealProgressButtonPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate._fraction != _fraction;
  }
}
```

You can read this [awesome tutorial for Circular reveal effect.](http://myhexaville.com/2018/05/14/flutter-circular-reveal-with-progress-button/) for detailed info.

**[Github Code](https://github.com/IhorKlimov/FlutterProgressButton)**

While doing reveal effect you have to open second screen smoothly. For this use [Fluro](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluro) library for routing and navigation. This will provide you Transition types.

```
router.navigateTo(context, "/profile_screen",transition: TransitionType.fadeIn,);
```